# Critical error after pause in swift 0 thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift

I had a pause in my project - 1 month. I saved working version. Now when i try debug without any change, app dripping error on thread 1: signal SIGABRT with this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/BillyBill
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1A1C365B-14A1-4438-9995-5622C7F9FAC3/BillyBill.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code Signature Invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066576/code-signature-invalid)

Comment: @Hassan sadly - no

Answer (score 0):

If you test your application on a physical device with iOS 13.3.1 and you are using `podfile`, it's a problem with a dynamic framework.
In your `podfile` comment the use_framework! line and run your pod install again.

Comment: Yes, its physical device. How i can do it (im new in swift).

Comment: in the root folder of your project, find podfile. Open it with your editor and comment the line start with `use_framework`. after that in the terminal, in your project directory type pod install, clean your project and it fixes